# Changing content of DOM text node

Tags: javascript, html, dom, textnode

Say I have the following HTML:

```
<div>Some text</div>
```

I'm wanting to remove the last character from the text each time the user hits the backspace key. Is there a way to actually remove a character from a text node? Or do I have to do something like `obj.innerText = 'Some tex'` (i.e. trim the last char myself and replace the whole thing).

Comment: You should look into a few frameworks/libraries that have these kind of view-model bindings baked in. http://angularjs.org/ or http://knockoutjs.com/ to name a few.

Comment: Have you tried [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_Editable)?

Answer (score 1):

```
var div = document.getElementById('my-div');
document.addEventListener('keydown', 
    function(e) {
        if (e.which === 8) {
            div.textContent = div.textContent.substring(0, div.textContent.length - 1);
        }
    }, false);
```

You may also want to support IE8. In that case, use document.attachEvent() and div.innerText.

Answer (score 0):

Best method I can think of off the top of my head is to use the `substring` method for Strings.

```
var s = obj.innerText

// Then On backspace event listener
s = s.substring(0, s.length - 1) // returns s without the last character in the original string.

obj.innerTezt(s) // set the inner HTML back to s
```

Edit: thanks Jonathan, Dennis for the correction on this answer!

Comment: You have the basic idea, but a few issues: 1) [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) is the standardized property and will need to be mixed with `innerText` for legacy support. 2) `s` isn't a *pointer* to `obj.innerText`; it's a copy. Setting it won't affect `obj.innerText` (or `obj.textContent`).

Comment: Nice catch! You're right Jonathan - I missed the last bit that he'd have to set innerText/innerHTML again after getting the substring!

Comment: `innerHTML` is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get the element
var el = document.queryString("...")

// Get the text contents
var text = el.firstChild
if (text.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
   // Delete the last character
   text.deleteData(text.length - 1, 1)
}
```

See the [CharacterData DOM interface](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#characterdata) for details of `deleteData`